# 2 Laser Mapping

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, gmapping, laser-assembler

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using 2 sick lms100 laser range finders for mapping. I am using Hydro. In my launch file I have both scans being sent to the same topic. The original idea was that I could use gmapping, as someone on this forum said that would work as long as the scans were both published to the same topic. Gmapping would hand;e the transforms. This turned out to be incorrect however, gmapping would only take data from one laser.

The next plan was to convert the laser scans into a point cloud and then send that to octomapping. I can use laser_scan_assembler from the laser_assembler package, but it puts out a service, not a topic. It seems that there used to be a node to republish that data, periodic_snapshotter, but apparently that doesn't work with Hydro. I have found the code and tried to convert it to use pointcloud2, but that didn't work. When I tried to make it with catkin it pulled up a bunch of errors. I also tried to make it with the original file which used pointcloud, but I got the same problems.

So, my question is does anyone have a program that will let me subscribe to a service and republish to a topic, or is there an easier way to do this?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/107791/2-laser-mapping/) by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) on ROS Answers with karma: 955 on 2013-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nevermind, I was able to find a git where periodic_snapshotter had been catkinized, and I updated it to work for PointCloud2.

---

Originally posted by [Icehawk101](https://answers.ros.org/users/4327/icehawk101/) with karma: 955 on 2013-12-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [redarean](https://answers.ros.org/users/4903/redarean/) on 2014-02-14**:
Alternately you could use point_cloud_converter to convert to pointcloud2 format
Check this out: http://answers.ros.org/question/9909/is-there-a-laser-assembler-that-produces-pointcloud2/?answer=16138#post-id-16138